# Error: ‘method’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

In my Method.h file:

```
int method();
```

In my Method.cpp file:

```
int method(){....}
```

In my Main.cpp file:

```
method();
```

In my Makefile

```
EXEC = main
OBJS = Method.o
.PHONY: all
all: $(EXEC)

main: Main.cpp $(OBJS)
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
Method.o : Method.h Method.cpp
```

When i call make, it says that

```
Main.cpp: In function ‘int menu()’:
Main.cpp:26: error: ‘method’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Can anybody tell me where I was wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you #include <Method.h> in your Main.cpp? A more complete view of the code would help.

Comment: Do you need any more information before selecting your favorite answer? :-)

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you include the method.h file in Main.cpp?

Comment: but i think when declaring makefile like that, the Main.cpp doesnot have to include the method.h again?

Comment: @user552279: Of course it does. This is the reason for header files existing! The compiler doesn't even know that it's `make` that invoked it.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>My first guess is to change the line</strike>

```
OBJS = Function.o
```

to

```
OBJS = Function.o Method.o
```

Also,  Include `Method.h` in `Main.cpp`

```
// In Main.cpp
#include "Method.h"
```